# Code signing VB Macros for a word doc... Code Cert issued and installed.. But macro still not trusted

Tags: vb.net, macros, certificate

So, I have a word document that has a VB Macro attached. Our company policy does not allow Macros to run without it being signed by an authenticated authority that I trust.

1. I have a Enterprise CA. I log in and request a code signing certificate. It downloads and installs.
2. I open the word document. It warns me as usual that the doc has a macro from an untrusted source. I go to developer tools. I uninstall the current cert (expired old company signature). I locate and add my own new code signing cert. I then save the document.
3. I open the document. It says this...

THE DIGITAL SIGNATURE IS VALID. BUT THE SIGNATURE IS FROM A PUBLISHER WHOM YOU HAVE NOT YET CHOSEN TO TRUST.

I have downloaded the CA cert. its in my trusted root cert directory but it still wont trust the content.

I'm at my wicks end :-(